# Dynamic tabs and tables in Rmarkdown with kable

Tags: r, dynamic, knitr

I am using the following code to create dynamic tabs with tables in Rmarkdown.

````
# TEST
``` {r echo=FALSE, results = 'asis', message = FALSE, warnings = FALSE}
print_month <- function(month) {
  cat("   \n##", format(month, "%B"), " results    \n")
  print(knitr::kable(data.frame(A = c(1,2,3), B = c(1,2,3))))
  cat("   \n")
}

seq.Date(from = ymd(20170101), to = ymd(20170601), by = 'month') %>%
  purrr::walk(print_month)
```
````

I have seen it working before, but I can't really narrow down why it fails sometimes. When it fails it looks like this
[image]

The tables are paragraphs when I look into the HTML code, but when working normally it should be rendered as a table...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the `print()` and `cat()` functions might be interacting with each other?

I prefer functions to return a single assembled string, and let the caller decide how to output it.

```
library(magrittr)
library(lubridate)
assemble_month <- function(month) {
  d <- mtcars[1:5, 1:6] #data.frame(A = c(1,2,3), B = c(1,2,3))
  html_table <- knitr::kable(d, format = "html")
  paste0(
    "\n##", format(month, "%B"), " results\n",
    html_table,
    "\n"
  )
}

seq.Date(from = ymd(20170101), to = ymd(20170601), by = 'month') %>%
  purrr::map_chr(assemble_month) %>% 
  cat()
```

[image]

A disadvantage with my approach though is it outputs the html table in a way fails to leverage knitr's nice markdown-to-html css formatting.  I typically add styling back with [kableExtra](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html), so `html_table` becomes

```
  html_table <- mtcars[1:5, 1:6] %>%
    knitr::kable(format = "html") %>%
    kableExtra::kable_styling(
      bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed", "responsive"), 
      full_width = F
    )
```

[image]

(I used a bigger example table to make it look more realistic.)